# Using PM2 list API to display visual table

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am using the PM2 API to manage a small cluster of processes. I'm wondering if it is possible to have my master.js file log the same visual table that is displayed when you run pm2 list from the command line? Currently, all I've come up with is...

```
pm2.list((err, processDescriptionList) => {

})
```